# How to temporarily switch to a headless environment in Windows?

Tags: windows, headless

On Linux, sometimes the display will freeze or something similar and it's necessary to switch to a headless environment. You can do this by typing Ctrl+Alt+F2, a shortcut that bypasses the display server and gives you the ability to log in to a command line environment.

How can I do something equivalent in Windows? Ctrl+Alt+Del does not help in this case because it does not switch to a headless environment.

Comment: Its not a headless environment, You're switching between virtual terminals. There's no equivalent in windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, cause of the architecture and design of windows and linux.

On linux you have *[virtual terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console)*, on top of which you run *X*. Calling a console 'headless' is inaccurate. A console is no less user interactive than a graphical interface.

Regular windows has a single VT equivalent, dedicated to running its equivalent of a window manager, even in minimal modes where all you do is run its equivalent of a terminal emulator.

*Amusingly* MS's nanoserver is *truly* headless. You can't even really configure it locally. It lacks VTs, and any ability to interact directly with the system.

So no. Neither linux nor windows are running 'headless' and the design of windows doesn't have an equivalent of of a VT

Comment: Ah. I was using "headless" as defined in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647719/what-does-headless-mean but I guess that it's not exactly the same